# linux bash - compare two files and remove duplicate lines having same ending

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have two files containing paths to files.

File 1

```
/home/anybody/proj1/hello.h
/home/anybody/proj1/engine.h
/home/anybody/proj1/car.h
/home/anybody/proj1/tree.h
/home/anybody/proj1/sun.h
```

File 2

```
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/cat.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/engine.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/tree.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/map.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/sun.h
```

I need a command, probably using grep, that would compare the two file and output a combination of the two files, but in case of duplicates in the name of the file, keep the file from File 2.

Expected output:

```
/home/anybody/proj1/hello.h
/home/anybody/proj1/car.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/cat.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/engine.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/tree.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/map.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/sun.h
```

This is so I can generate a list of include files for my project's tag database, but some files are duplicated by the build, and I don't want to have two copies of the same file in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` command should do the job:

```
awk -F/ 'NR == FNR{a[$NF]=$0; next} !($NF in a); END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file2 file1

/home/anybody/proj1/hello.h
/home/anybody/proj1/car.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/map.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/cat.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/engine.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/tree.h
/home/anybody/proj2/module/include/sun.h
```

Comment: This will include a line feed!!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that. This is as per the sample data provided.

Comment: I tried the same and it included a line feed between proj1 and proj2

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
cat file2 file1 | awk -F '/' '
{ if (a[$NF] == "") a[$NF] = $0 }
END { for (k in a) print a[k] }' | sort
```

Comment: Data is not sorted

Comment: I extended my script. But usually databases can handle unsorted data